sudo apt update not working getting the error shown below
I am using Ubuntu 24.04. sudo apt install, sudo apt update or sudo apt upgrade, any of these type of commands that start with sudo apt are not working and giving this output. I just changed some properties in Software & Updates.
Output:-
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://releases.warp.dev/linux/deb/ stable: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/warpdotdev.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I had removed the file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/warpdotdev.gpg but it still showing this error. I cannot open Software and updates.
This is the output of cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d  && ls:-
google-chrome.list       ubuntu-esm-apps.sources.save   ubuntu.sources              warpdotdev.list       winehq-noble.sources.save
google-chrome.list.save  ubuntu-esm-infra.sources       ubuntu.sources.curtin.orig  warpdotdev.list.save
ubuntu-esm-apps.sources  ubuntu-esm-infra.sources.save  ubuntu.sources.save         winehq-noble.sources


Are you using any software from warpdotdev? If not, you can disable the software source entry for it (in the "Other Software") tab, and then run sudo apt update to fix the problem.

i am not able to open Software and updates. I cannot disable it.

Alright. Please edit the question and post the output of cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d  && ls

Posted the output.

Most likely the warpdotdev.list entry is malformed.
Run the following command to remove it:
sudo rm /etc/sources.list.d/warpdotdev.list

And then run sudo apt update.
